# CMake Error - WritingPublisherSubscriber(c++)

Tags: ros, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm new to ROS and browsing ROS tutorials I'm stuck with the problem in Writing a Simple Publisher and Subs.. tutorial.

Basically I followed it till the end and finally when I want to execute the catkin_make in catkin_ws $ I get an error message

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:94 (message):
  add_message_files() directory not found:
  /home/hyuu/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:8 (add_message_files)
```

This is how my CMakeLists.txt inside beginner_tutorials folder looks like(copy-paste from tutorials):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)

## Declare ROS messages and services
add_message_files(DIRECTORY msg FILES Num.msg)
add_service_files(DIRECTORY srv FILES AddTwoInts.srv)

## Generate added messages and services
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package()

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

Thanks for any help provided!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269910/cmake-error---writingpublishersubscriber(c++)/) by [hyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31741/hyuu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-08-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-08-30**:
Do you actually have a `/home/hyuu/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg` directory? Is your Num.msg file in that directory? If yes to both, what are the permissions on the directory and file?

**Comment by [hyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31741/hyuu/) on 2017-08-30**:
Actually I did everything as described in tutorial and I do not have that folder or any file. I browsed a lot of different answers but none of them helped me. Did I miss some steps? I assumed it's made automatically or sth.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-08-31**:
The Creating a ROS msg and srv tutorial that @jayess linked to in his answer has a section where you specifically create the message and service files in the `msg/` and `srv/` directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you copy and paste it? In the tutorial, the [CMakeLists.txt](https://raw.github.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/master/create_package_pubsub/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt) has the following lines

```
add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)
```

but you have

```
add_message_files(DIRECTORY msg FILES Num.msg)
add_service_files(DIRECTORY srv FILES AddTwoInts.srv)
```

Notice the difference? Yours says `DIRECTORY msg` and `DIRECTORY srv` while the tutorial only says `FILES`.

Also, the [Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) presumes that you completed the [Creating a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) tutorial where the `msg` and `srv` folders and definitions for the custom message and service are created.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hyuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31741/hyuu/) on 2017-08-30**:
Thanks! I copied the part from the code above, not the final part. Still didn't solve my problem but probably that I missed this Creating ROS msg and srv tutorial made this problem :/

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-08-31**:
While the CMakeLists.txt file linked in this answer is different than the OP's file (and fixes the error), it's worth pointing out that [file in the WritingPublisherSubscriber(c++) tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) is the same as the OP's file

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-08-31**:
This version works correctly as long as you follow the instructions in the CreatingMsgAndSrv tutorial (which is the previous tutorial) which has you [create Num.msg](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg) in the `msg/` directory of your package.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-31**:
@jarvisschultz: Thanks for pointing out that the one that the OP posted is in the tutorial. There are actually *two* CMakeLists.txt which doesn't help clear the confusion. The one that I used is underneath the one that @hyuu used. I scrolled from the bottom up so I didn't see the first one.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-31**:
But, the tutorial says that the final one should be the one that I linked to.